# How can I create thousands of variables rather than using DataFrame (too slow)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

#### Question

How can I create thousands of variables rather than using DataFrame? Updating elements with

```
df1.loc[a,b] = df1.loc[a,b] + update_term
```

is so slow!!!

#### Current situation

1. I have 2500 days' historical prices of 445 U.S. companies in a dataframe. ( 2500 rows * 445 columns DataFrame)
2. What I am trying to do with these prices of stocks is calculating 3 parameters of the equation shown below.
   [image]
   Since each 445 company has a<sub>k</sub>, b<sub>k</sub> (445 each) and pairs of 445 companies has   w<sub>j,k</sub> parameters ((445 * 444) /2 in total) , there are so many variables to create.
3. To make the variables needed for parameters above, I have made 3 dataframes, 2 of which are 1*445 dimension (1row, 445 columns) for a<sub>k</sub>, b<sub>k</sub> and 445 * 445 dimension for w<sub>j,k</sub>. A screenshot for this are shown below.
   [image]
4. Since I update the parameters for each company using df.loc function like

`parameter = parameter + df.loc[date,'company_name']`

my codes are so slow!!

A real example from my code is shown below.

```
A_random_parameter = df1.loc['row_index_1',company_x] +
    df2.loc['row_index_2',company_x] *
    df3.loc[date,'company_y']
```

Any suggestion to create thousands of variables rather than using DataFrame-like way?

Comment: Post realistic code, maybe we can help you then.  Or try using `dict` instead of `DataFrame`.

Comment: have you tried to use `DataFrame.apply()`? That is a lot faster. Also have a look at `statsmodels`, what you want to do is likely implemented there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use arrays

If you need to run matrix calculations like the one shown in your equation, you'd want to use a data structure with fast random element access and a contiguous memory layout. In python, the standard way to do that is using numpy arrays (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

Furthermore, in any such operations where you care about performance you *DO NOT* want to do a python loop and access/update each element individually. Not if you're using pandas dataframes, not if you're using numpy arrays, not if you're using tensorflow or anything else. Instead, you'd want to 'vectorize' the operations, i.e. use basic operations that work on whole vectors or matrixes "at once" so that the appropriate libraries can effectively parallelize their execution where possible. [NumPy Basics: Arrays and Vectorized Computation](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html) may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that using dictionary is much faster than using DataFrame for storing variables, as John Zwinck suggested. Thank you!